# loading spinner in symfony when opening the page

Tags: jquery, symfony

I would like to show a spinner in my symfony project when the page is loading.

The spinner would show immediatly after a page is open, and when the page is loaded, it would disapear.

I would prefer a solution using JQuery.

Maybe I should use a kernel event, but I dont know how to implement it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are completely wrong ... 

To achieve your goal, you have to use jquery only. Loading spinners will come most on the client side if you are using XHTML Requests (called ajax in jquery).

Look into jquery $.ajax function and specialy there for the beforeSend and complete methods, then you will have a clue how it works.

Comment: i already use spinner in my ajax calls. I want to use it for normal php pages, knowing i dont make ajax calls, only classic php with symfony.

Comment: Then you have to go with onbeforeunload function respectively with onLoad function of body element. But still on the clientside with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, for displaying the spinner, when the site does unload. Maybe some tweaking is necessary ( nodeName Check ) and surely the action you would execute if the pages does unload.

Add this lines of code at the end of your page, shortly before /body

```
<script>
    function unLoader(e) {
        if(e.target.nodeName != '#document') {
            $('#pageBody').hide("fade", null, 5000).css('background', '');
        }
    }
    $(function() {
        $('#pageBody').show("fade",null,500).css('background','');
        window.onbeforeunload = unLoader;
    });
</script>
```